# HDinsight clusters provisioned through the .net SDK: All MapReduce jobs run with 1 reducer

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm relatively inexperienced with Hadoop, but I've been using boilerplate code for the last year or so, writing and submitting C# MapReduce console applications via the HDInsight .net SDK.

These jobs seem to constantly run with many mappers, but only one reducer.

My reducers do a fair amount of heavy lifting, so having just one reducer seems like a heck of a bottleneck. Often I can RDP into the cluster and watch the jobs run like liquid gold, then grind to a... grindingly slow thing when the reducer kicks in).

How can I control the amount of resource applied to the reducer? Can I direct more resources to the reducers rather than the mappers?

The clusters are spun up programatically (as per [here](https://gist.github.com/AzimUddin/11025548#file-hdinsight_cluster_customization_via_sdk-cs)) - I can see that I can control various parameters in the config files: am I on the right track? Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the no. of reducers you want your job to use by using the "mapred.reduce.tasks" config. The one reducer you are seeing is the default.

Using HDInsight .net SDK, this can be set at job level using the "Defines" property of [MapReduceJobCreateParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hadoop.client.mapreducejobcreateparameters.defines.aspx)

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/02/13/how-to-pass-hadoop-configuration-values-for-a-job-via-hdinsight-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx) has an example on how to define additional configs for job

Comment: Excellent! I got this working by setting the "mapred.reduce.tasks" config in mapred-site.xml when spinning up the cluster with clusterInfo.MapReduceConfiguration.ConfigurationCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mapred.reduce.tasks", "4"));

Comment: Glad you got it working. I would like to point out that you updated the default value which is good enough if you don't expect the size of your workload to change. If not, tuning this config at job level is ideal. There is useful documentation on how to choose reducers count on [hadoop wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces)